# jquery notification bars that can be dismissed?

Tags: jquery, html, notifications

I've been looking for a notification bar like the one on this site that displays at the top notifying a user of changes etc. It should have the ability of being closed. All I can find for jquery is [this one](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/29/jbar-a-jquery-notification-plugin/)

Does anyone have any other recommendations or suggestions?

Comment: It is *really* easy to make. Even this site has one!

Comment: @Blender: "Even this" sounds as it is simple because *even* Stackoverflow got it running.

Comment: Most of the stuff on this site is quite minimal and simple (and obviously well-coded).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Super easy to build your own. Just make it the first `<div>` under the `<body>` tag, and set the css to something like this:

```
#notify {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    background-color:orange;
    height:50px;
    color:white;
    display:none;
}
```

Then on your notifications, simply slide it down:

```
$('#notify').html('new message').slideDown();
```

And add a click event to close it and clear out the notification:

```
$('#notify').click(function(){
    $(this).slideUp().empty();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/Azh4b/

If you wanted to really make it like StackOverflow's you'd simply set a cookie when you issue the notification, and then every page load show all notifications which have applicable cookies.

**If you want multiple notifications**, change `#notify` to `.notify` and stack em up. Something like this:

```
$('.notify').live('click',function() {
    $(this).slideUp('fast',function(){$(this).remove();});
});

$(function(){
    notify('You have earned the JQuery badge!');
    notify('You have earned the Super Awesome badge!');
});

function notify(msg) {
    $('<div/>').prependTo('body').addClass('notify').html(msg).slideDown();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/5hjPY/

Comment: Never considered building my own...makes sense. Thanks and thank you for the great example :)

Answer (score 2):

I've actually made something very similar to this for a couple of projects of mine.

There's a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eQjzc/1/), which works but it's a straight lift from my personal libs - code that could probably use cleaning and optimising, but it give a good impression of how it works.

The added bonus of my code is that it doesn't show duplicate items - it "pings" the currently existing one. Clicking anywhere on the notification closes it.

The only drawback I can see for this is that it covers up some of the main content, but that's fixable if you put the notifications container at the top of your content with `position: static`.

Please let me know if there are any specifics you want me to explain; there's rather a lot of code to run through in one answer.

*I'll probably write a jQuery plugin that does this at some point, seeing as there's only one example. I'll post it here when I do.*

---

NB. The `setInterval()` is only used for demonstration purposes. Also, there are different coloured alerts (success, info, warning, error - green, blue, orange and red respectively).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try "noty"
https://github.com/needim/noty