# .slideDown() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This should be easy but I checked on google and did not find any info on this.

I am doing:

```
        $notification.slideDown(1000, function(){
            $('#notifications').append($notification);
        });
```

However it is not sliding down. It is getting displayed without any animation. No error either.

`.slideUp()` is working properly.
What am I doing wrong here?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7b3j2/28/)

Comment: jsfiddle by ny chance?

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/7b3j2/28/

Comment: What should actually happen?I just typed something and submitted and a dialog box appeard and got cancelled once I cancelled it

Comment: The dialog box should slideDown()

Comment: it slides down on mine...below the editor,and once i add new text again,the new text gets appeneded below the first one

Comment: i don't know if it exactly what you need, but you can try this answer here: [jquery notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464714/jquery-notification-bars-that-can-be-dismissed)

Comment: @user3040563 It is not working for me. I checked on both, Chrome and Firefox. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
  $notification.slideDown(1000, function () {
     $('#notifications').append($notification);
 });
```

to

```
  $('#notifications').append($notification.hide());
        $notification.slideDown(1000);
```

The reason why slideDown doesn't work is because the element is visible when you are appending it

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7b3j2/32/)

Also note that when you slideUp the notification you should remove it because otherwise you'll have multiple notifications just taking up place

```
$closeButton.click(function () {
    $(this).parent().slideUp(function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) documentation says:

```
$notification.slideDown(1000, function(){});
```

here function executes on sliding complete. So you need to append hidden element then slidDown to show.

```
$('#notifications').append($notification.hide());
$notification.slideDown(1000);
```

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/7b3j2/33/)

Comment: And how would I append it to `#notifications`.

Answer (score 0):

You had two minor issues, first your `.notification` element needs to be hidden to be able to `slideDown()`.

```
.notification{
    display: none;
}
```

Secondly, you were trying to animate in an element that doesn't exist until the animation is complete :)

```
    $notification.slideDown(1000, function(){
        $('#notifications').append($notification);
    });
```

Updated script below. **PS: Don't forget to add the CSS snipplet.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'description' );

    $('#title').focus();

    $('form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var html=CKEDITOR.instances.description.getSnapshot();

        var $closeButton = $('<img class="closeButton" src="http://www.tunesdiary.com/static/images/icon_grey_cross.gif">');
        var $title = $('<span></span>').addClass('title').text($('#title').val());
        var $description = $('<span></span>').addClass('description').html(html);
        var $notification = $('<div></div>').append($closeButton).append($title).append($description).addClass('notification');
        $('#notifications').append($notification);
        $notification.slideDown(1000);

        $closeButton.click(function(){
            $(this).parent().slideUp();
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Also, you might want to try using a third party library for this kind of stuff, it is a lot cleaner to invoke a custom script instead of writing your own elements each time you need to show an alert.

I have personally used: http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/ and find it very strong :)